# how to add namespace and new attribute to root node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am using xslt to add namespace and new attribute to root node.I need to make this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Document Hub="" DocType="Invoice" ID="" BatchNumber="" DocumentCreatedDate="2016-08-09">
        <HeaderInformation></HeaderInformation>      
        <Summary></Summary>
</Document>
```

To be Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="http://Anylink" Hub="ADP" DocumentCreatedDate="2016-08-09" PartnershipId="123">
        <HeaderInformation></HeaderInformation>      
        <Summary></Summary>
     </Document>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what problem you are having? In particular it would help if you showed how the `$QueryResult` was defined, as this is very important in how the XSLT is applied. Thank you!

Comment: $QueryResult is variable i define to get data from database


<xsl:variable name="QueryResult"> 
        <sql:query connection="$connection" table="document_properties" column="*" row-tag="Partner" 
                   '/> 
    </xsl:variable>